Google Ad Mobs Flutter error No Ad Config
I just want to try how to use an ad in my application using flutter, but I receiving an error message like this
Ad failed to load : 3

LoadAdError(code: 3, domain: com.google.android.gms.ads, message: No ad config., 
responseInfo: ResponseInfo(responseId: null, mediationAdapterClassName: , 
adapterResponses: [], loadedAdapterResponseInfo: null), responseExtras: {})

the main problem is like that and I literally don't know what happened and just searching the same problem in this platform but it didn't solve mine, whether I'm using the testID in the documentation or using the real AdID the AdMob gave it to me it the same, still error
this is my code
main.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_mobile_ads/google_mobile_ads.dart';
import 'package:myapp/IklanScreen.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  MobileAds.instance.initialize();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

this is the AndroidManifest.xml value data
 <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713"/>

and this is the screen that I want to make the ad show up
IklanScreen.dart
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_mobile_ads/google_mobile_ads.dart';

class IklanScreen extends StatefulWidget{
  IklanScreen({Key? key}):super(key: key);

  @override
  _IklanScreen createState() => _IklanScreen();
}

class _IklanScreen extends State<IklanScreen>{
  BannerAd? _bannerAd;
  bool _isloaded = false;
  
  final adUnitId = Platform.isAndroid
    ? 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111' //android
    : 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716';//ios

  void loadAd() {
    _bannerAd = BannerAd(
      adUnitId: adUnitId,
      request: const AdRequest(),
      size: AdSize.banner,
      listener: BannerAdListener(
        // Called when an ad is successfully received.
        onAdLoaded: (ad) {
          debugPrint('$ad loaded.');
          setState(() {
            _isloaded = true;
          });
        },
        // Called when an ad request failed.
        onAdFailedToLoad: (ad, err) {
          debugPrint('BannerAd failed to load: $err');
          // Dispose the ad here to free resources.
          ad.dispose();
        },
      ),
    )..load();
  }


  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    loadAd();
  }

  @override
  void dispose(){
    _bannerAd?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          if(_bannerAd != null && _isloaded)
            Container(
              height: _bannerAd!.size.height.toDouble(),
              width: _bannerAd!.size.width.toDouble(),
              child: AdWidget(ad: _bannerAd!),
            )
        ],
      ),
    );

  }

}

I'm just tested it using the testID and real ID still facing the same problem, I just make the device got registered in the google ad mobs and still same, and nor the documentation and the same reference in this topic still relevant after I tried, and Just make it the admob application has the same name with the project still doesn't help
Can You guys help me? I just struggled for over the past few weeks
Thank You and really appreciated

Just in Case, I just copy entirely the project documentation on the google admob for banner in lib folder and still it has the same problem with me, follow the tutorial on youtube, still make me face the same problem

I faced issue in emulator and was able to solve the issue by running code in physical device
